# Viewing cell address after calculation

Tags: excel-formula

I have built the macro as following and it is working well. However, I have a problem with this. I want to see how the calculations in each cell was performed such as in "$B$6+A6" format in the original excel file but I am unable to do so. It would be really nice if you can help me out with this.

Thank you very much

```
Sub RCinput()

Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim d As Long
Dim e As Long




 a = InputBox("What is the row number: ")

 b = InputBox("What is the column number: ")

 c = InputBox("What is the last row number: ")

 e = b - 1


For d = a To c

Cells(d, b).Formula = Cells(d, e).Value * 2

Next


End Sub
```

Comment: have the macro print out the formula / intermediate results...

Comment: I am sorry I could not understand. I do not want to print it out, I just want to view how the calculations in each cell were performed as we normally see in excel but with the above code

Comment: Then I don't understand - please edit - rephrase and clarify exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see your formula is equal to value, therefore you receive a number as a result. Please try to modify your code like this:

```
Sub RCinput()

Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim d As Long
Dim e As Long

 a = InputBox("What is the row number: ")

 b = InputBox("What is the column number: ")

 c = InputBox("What is the last row number: ")

 e = b - 1

For d = a To c

Cells(d, b).Formula = "=" & Cells(d, e).Address & "* 2"

Next

End Sub
```

Part `Cells(d, b).Formula = "=" & Cells(d, e).Address & "*2"` will put in `Cells(d,b)` a formula e.g. `"=$A$1*2"`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It worked perfectly. How do I make it as a relative reference instead of absolute. Also, I want to do special operations like sqrt(), exp, or log. I am trying to do it as you did with the above but it seems I cannot get it.

Comment: I think I found the way to do the relative referencing but I am still stuck with the special mathemetical operations with the above style

Comment: For relative formulas you should change `.Address` to `.Address(False, False)`. If you would like to have "exp" in formula you should put is a string in the formula. For example `Cells(d, b).Formula = "=exp(" & Cells(d, e).Address(False, False) & ") " & "*2"`

Comment: Thank you very much